# Get Revit Views in Model Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

I'm looking at an application using the forge viewer converting Revit models.  I would like to be able to reproduce the 3D views that are saved in the Revit model in the viewer, is this possible?

For example if I create multiple 3D views in the Revit model I would like to be able to list them in the viewer and navigate to them programmatically when I want to.  I'm not finding much documentation on the website but I tried uploading to Docs and it appears to only have the default 3D view (there are several saved in the Revit model).  It also has the 2D sheets which is fine but I'm interested in the 3D views.  If the information is in there where do I find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you didn't configure the [publish settings](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/revit/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2023/ENU/Revit-Cloud/files/GUID-09FBF9E2-6ECF-447D-8FA8-12AB16495BC3-htm.html) in Revit before uploading to BIM360. Please do the following to fix it.

1. Open the RVT with Revit Desktop.
2. Go to "Collaborate > Manage Models panel > Publish Settings".
3. Ensure you have selected either view set and made it active.
4. Ensure select your 3D views and other views you want to see in the active view set.
5. Save the change into the RVT
6. Reupload the modified RVT to BIM360 Docs.

You can find my detailed explanations here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GgW9gBCRrWg

Comment: Ah, thank makes sense and was the missing piece I was looking for.  Thanks!